# How can I recover the Wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel

I have a problem that makes elementary OS unable to start pantheon; it just stays showing the wallpaper in the lockscreen after I write my password.
It all started when the Wingpanel became a little bit buggy just after booting; it didn't show the icons or the time for some minutes. I decided to uninstall and reinstall it, and my user never started again. Need some help.

Comment: Do you use the "eos daily repository"? I had a similar problem with wingpanel. It took about one minute to start and show all the icons. But slingshot was available so I could start my apps. I could find out that there is a problem with "parentel control" and I removed the switchboard plugin. Now it seems to work. In the past few days I played around and changed many files - so I don't know if parental control is really the reason. But for me it works now.